# How to multiply in sqldf statements using an external float variable

Tags: r, sqldf

I have problems multiplying numbers of an external variable in sqldf
In the projection of the SQL statement I would like to multiply the value of a column with an external float variable input$euro (e.g. 0.23).

```
data <- read.csv("consumption1.csv", sep=",", header=T,skip =1)
colnames(data)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(data)[2] <- "HeatProduction"
sqldf("select Date, (HeatProduction/3*'%f') as HeatProduction from data where Date like '2014%' order by Date", input$euro)
```

It seems to me the result is always rounded to 0. My question is also if this is a sensible way to construct the query. The problem might have to do with SQLite.

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your data (e.g. `dput(data[1:10,])`)?

Comment: Plesae provide a complete self-contained example.  Also see example 5 on the sqldf home page.

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
inputEuro <- input$euro
fn$sqldf("select Date, (HeatProduction/3 * $inputEuro) as HeatProduction
          from data
          where Date like '2014%'
          order by Date")
```

See [example 5 for sqldf external variables](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_5._Insert_Variables)